# Visual Studio is opening with multiple solutions when I only want one

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am making a Unity project using visual studio, and anytime I open up VS via opening a script in Unity, the VS project connected opens multiple solutions and a warning window pops up saying: [disc of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3HA5.png)

This error does not keep me from using VS, but I think it is interfering with Intellisense, as I am only able to autocomplete some data. Also, I believe references from any "using" namespaces other than the 3 that automatically appear on scripts, show up as errors.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest Visual Studio Tools for Unity installed. It will always show at least 3 projects because there are 3 different assemblies. You may want to read a bit about how that interaction happens and what you can access from where.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I figured out the issue. I re-updated VS from the installer. The thing is I did that before.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that visual studio needs to be updated. Open up the Unity installer, and proceed to the page that allows you to select optional components to install. There, select Visual Studio, and continue the installation. That will make sure that a proper version of visual studio is installed and that it is configured to interact properly with Unity.